# insert object in mongoose schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

i have a object like

```
otp:{
      otpCode: 2589,
      expiresAt: 1590363562131,   //result of date.now()
      status: 0                   //(0:unused, 1:unused, 2:expired)
    }
```

how to create a schema to store this object. I don't want to use array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

added the schema like this:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
     otp: {
      code: {
        type: Number
      },
      expiresAt: {
        type: Number
      },
      status: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
      }
    }
  }
);
export default userSchema;
```